# Is there any plugin/component that lets me populate data for aerospike upon spin up like liquibase does for mysql?

Tags: mysql, microservices, liquibase, key-value, aerospike

Say I have a microservice A that uses aerospike as a key-value store. I need some information on any component/plugin that lets me populate initial data in aerospike that might be a pre-requisite for the microservice to spin up.

So, if I were to deploy this service along with its own instances of aerospike, I would want, aerospike instances to be spun up, a healthcheck component packaged with the microservice, that would check for the health of aerospike, after which it would populate the discovered aerospike with data based on any scripts that I might specify, post which it would spin up the service with it pointing to the, now-populated aerospike .

The functionality I'm looking for is akin to that provided by liquibase for Mysql where I can specify scripts to populate mysql with whatever data/schema, before spinning up a microservice that is dependent on that to be populated data in Mysql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have the initialization data in a text file created previously using asbackup. Then on startup restore the data with asrestore. Both asbackup and asrestore are standalone applications. More about asbackup/asrestore [here](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/tools/backup/index.html).